# Story Id: Stepping through a portal to a haunted mansion

Tags: story-identification

I apologize for not having many details about the story, as I read it in grade school and only just remembered it.

The story involved a young boy and several other individuals going through some sort of portal or doorway to a haunted/magic mansion, where the rooms and doorways moved around and they had to escape.  I remember the book having lots of black and white sketch-like illustrations, and I believe the author had other similar look and feel books (black and white sketches, eerie magical things, etc).

I know it's not a lot to go on, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When were you in grade school? Was the book geared towards that age range? Was it English? Did it seem to be translated?

Comment: I read the book in the early 2000s, though I could not tell you when it was published.  The book seemed to be geared towards the 10-12 age range, or thereabouts.  It was in English, and did not seem translated.